# Is It possible to use single mass transit rabbit mq consumer for multiple kafka cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, kafka-consumer-api, masstransit

In the current set up single kafka cluster and single mass transit rabbit mq consumer is used.
But in the new requirement two kafka clusters being created on different nodes .
Please note there will be different messages produced on both Kafka clusters in active-active manner

1. Can we use same consumer to consume message from dual kafka clusters?
2. is it a good practice to use single consumer for dual kafka cluster?

Any other best approach to tackle this requirement?